# pulling data from web search form using Rcurl/httr

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I'm a beginner in web scraping and not trying to figure out the issue I am facing in pulling the data from web search form.

The form looks something like below.

Details of practitioner

Given name:
Gender

My code looks like below.

```
  pars <- list('Given Name' = "Price", Gender = 'Male' )
  html.post= postForm("url.aspx",
               .params = pars,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))

  cat(html.post,file = ".//temp.html",append=FALSE)
```

the link to the site I am searching is:[Link](https://www.gmc-uk.org/registration-and-licensing/the-medical-register#searchTheRegister)

but I am not getting data after the passing the above values.

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong.

Any help from you will be gratefull.

Comment: Can you provide the link of the website you are trying to scrape.

Comment: @ dimitris_ps: the link is  http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&_sn=bx5WiC.Raa.SYqbnVtdnDW2rzaI8FAhP6LIIZidsaFQ7mFgRcL9RMEGs5G1iZYGFhJQFTxPGGcTusD5UHTnjx7vw3M2GH5ckKQE1bzd-N1QM8fDrNn7PpvmuWs14rgCsyPMFfg2oz3RmTO0aE6hJaMKWpflME90ANAFZCa.L5NW5A9on8rf4ZdVCnr1Mwkb.kwiDKB2kdPI_&SWEView=GMC+WEB+Doctor+Search&SRN=&SWEHo=webcache.gmc-uk.org&SWETS=1429625652&SWEApplet=GMC+WEB+Health+Provider+Search+Applet

Comment: Could you also provide a valid case, i.e. what would you input by hand, so i can test the code.

Comment: @dimitris_ps, i would like to find all the names that have the Given Name: Joy, Gender: Male.

Comment: I am looking at the output as in the below link,

http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&_sn=7lYQP0WIp964hcn0kxE3SNZeulTN02QlnfXsv2tk8hsowy2l9IoCNqXcDSjaMFo5Bkr2VQKeXN49uLjT.95fAUjii6MLAuNpA1NXecJGJ377uiiDgMK-4f12.t9TSF2CnnEL1mClmG-dkQnh57z779qj0oE2sj8hXDcJnb4xBwVFgTMhGTMZjfnW6ju8jMrZT1b4H17X3DQ_&SWEView=GMC+WEB+Doctor+Search&SRN=&SWEHo=webcache.gmc-uk.org&SWETS=1429691562&SWEApplet=GMC+WEB+Health+Provider+Search+Applet

Comment: The website is in JS, you could try looking into `RSelenium`.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your link in my code below (your link was missing an ':') this code gets data and prints it out. Good luck.

```
library(RCurl)
library(httr)

target.url <- 'http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&_sn=bx5WiC.Raa.SYqbnVtdnDW2rzaI8FAhP6LIIZidsaFQ7mFgRcL9RMEGs5G1iZYGFhJQFTxPGGcTusD5UHTnjx7vw3M2GH5ckKQE1bzd-N1QM8fDrNn7PpvmuWs14rgCsyPMFfg2oz3RmTO0aE6hJaMKWpflME90ANAFZCa.L5NW5A9on8rf4ZdVCnr1Mwkb.kwiDKB2kdPI_&SWEView=GMC%20WEB%20Doctor%20Search&SRN=&SWEHo=webcache.gmc-uk.org&SWETS=1429625652&SWEApplet=GMC%20WEB%20Health%20Provider%20Search%20Applet'

pars <- list('Given Name' = "Price", Gender = 'Male' )
html.post = postForm(target.url, .params = pars,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
print(html.post)
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. But I am not getting the ouput with the required results. It just giving me the a html code.